# Check & Compare file permission

Tags: python, python-2.7

I write this code. But it look like amateur. Could you help improve my code ? (Line 11, x will return 0644 - Line 12 too bad :D )
This code using for check file permission and file permission need lower 0600. Thank so much !!!

```
def split(word):
  return [char for char in word]

def per_sshpri_configured(path, perm):
  pattern = '^Access: \((\d{4})\/.'
  r=[sp_util(['find /etc/ssh -xdev -type f -name "{}" -exec \
    stat {} \;'.format(path,'{}'), 'grep "Access: ("'])]
  for r1 in r:
    match = re.search(pattern, r1)
    if match:
      x = split(match.group(1))
      if int(x[0]) == 0 and int(x[1]) <=6 and int(x[2]) <=6 and int(x[3]) <=0:
        return True
      else:
        return False
```

Comment: What does "Line 12 too bad" mean? Does the code not work correctly?

Comment: Are you really using Python 2.7 and not Python 3?

Comment: Line 12 still working. But can we improve it ?

Comment: Yes, i using python 2.7